# Sorting Sub array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to sort a document from MongoDb with the values of a subarray but i don't get what i want.

Example :
Input JSON :

```
[{
    _id : 512,
    Categories : 
    [
        {
            _id : 1,
            Ranking : 3,
            Type : 'Property',
            Value : 'Value 1'
        },
        {
            _id : 12,
            Ranking : 2,
            Type : 'Argument',
            Value : 'Value 2'
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id : 100,
    Categories : 
    [
        {
            _id : 4,
            Ranking : 2,
            Type : 'Property',
            Value : 'Value 21'
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id : 122,
    Categories : 
    [
        {
            _id : 31,
            Ranking : 1,
            Type : 'Argument',
            Value : 'Value 1'
        },
        {
            _id : 12,
            Ranking : 1,
            Type : 'Property',
            Value : 'Value 12'
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I want to sort the elements with the Ranking field where the Type est Property.

Final Result :

```
[
{
    _id : 122,
    Categories : 
    [
        {
            _id : 31,
            Ranking : 1,
            Type : 'Argument',
            Value : 'Value 1'
        },
        {
            _id : 12,
            Ranking : 1,
            Type : 'Property',
            Value : 'Value 12'
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id : 100,
    Categories : 
    [
        {
            _id : 4,
            Ranking : 2,
            Type : 'Property',
            Value : 'Value 21'
        }
    ]
}
{
    _id : 512,
    Categories : 
    [
        {
            _id : 1,
            Ranking : 3,
            Type : 'Property',
            Value : 'Value 1'
        },
        {
            _id : 12,
            Ranking : 2,
            Type : 'Argument',
            Value : 'Value 2'
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I tried to do like this :

```
db.Collection.aggregate(
     { $match: {
        'Categories.Type' : 'Property'
    }},
    { $sort: {
        'Categories.Ranking' : 1
    }}
)
```

--> This give me the result in the wrong order

I tried also this :

```
db.Collection.aggregate(
     { $unwind: '$Categories' },
     { $match: {
        'Categories.Type' : 'Property'
    }},
    { $sort: {
        'Categories.Ranking' : 1
    }}
)
```

--> The final result is OK but i need the other fields with the Argument Type in my result.

Can anybody help ?

Thanks !

Comment: What if the document has two array element with `"type" : "property"`? How do you sort using the `ranking` in that case? Use the lower ranking? The higher ranking?

Comment: In my case, i can't have two types with the same value.